# overflow:auto not working in touch devices(iOS)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit, scroll

I have implemented a website using twitter bootstrap. At the top of the site I have used a nav bar, and inside that used a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is made up of < ul > and < li > tags. I am showing a list of members inside that dropdwon menu. When the list of member grows the dropdown menu grows horizontally, for which I have added a `overflow: auto` to the dropdown-menu class. Now its showing an vertical scroll bar, and working fine in browser.

But the same thing is not working in iPad and other iOs devices. I have googled it and found `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` should work. But it is not working for me. Lot of other solutions are also present, but unfortunately not working for me.

Is there any better solution available. May be anything we can do using css itself.

Comment: use both `overflow: scroll` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. [link](http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/). and also have a look at this link [**Barrow.io**](http://barrow.io/overflow-scrolling)

Comment: Yeah, everywhere its written that -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; should work, but don't know why its not working for me.

Comment: use with `overflow: scroll` not with `overflow: auto`..

Comment: Is it not working because I am trying to use it for a < ul > tag, and it should work for a < div > ? Since I am using twitter bootstrap dropdwon-menu, I am not able add a > div > there.

Answer (score 3):

Add the css property in to your div tag -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Comment: I have to display the scroll bar in < ul > and < li > tag.

Comment: put it in a container and in css add that property