# Mobile/iOS Overflow:auto Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Edit: The difference is I'm using their solution and it's not working.

I have a horizontal scroller website. I'm working on making it so the page will scroll horizontally not down. This code is working on desktops to scroll horizontally but it is NOT working on mobile. How would I fix this?

Thanks!

```
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#slides-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#slides{
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto; 
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: change `overflow-x` to `scroll`, not `auto`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overflow:auto not working in touch devices(iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438690/overflowauto-not-working-in-touch-devicesios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is working on a horizontal scroller and is trying to implement the ability for users to scroll horizontally on web and mobile this was the solution I finally found to work in my case:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Hope it's helpful. Thanks!